# Formatting time from dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss to yyyy.mm.dd hh:mm

Tags: excel, vba

I received the following task:
turn "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss" time to "yyyy.mm.dd hh:mm" format.

I was hoping that a simple Format(activecell.value, "yyyy.mm.dd hh:mm") would help, but.
In some cases it works. However, in some special cases, it doesn't.
When the day is between 01-12 (interchangeable with months!), then it messes up the days with months. (Probably because of US style date format.)

For example, original text string:
04/06/2013 09:00:00

Expected:
2013.06.04 09:00

Result:
2013.04.06 09:00 (day and month have been swapped)

I tried to overcome it by formatting the input, I gave it a "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss" custom format. Didn't help, it still swaps the day and the month.

So I have no ideas anymore, but regular expressions. Date format is always the same so just moving the parts of the string would be okay.
However, I don't know how that works and google searching brings up confusing results.

Can anyone help me?
Of course if there is a more elegant way to do it, that's also welcome.

Comment: How did the dates get into the worksheet? If it was badly imported, errors like this (mix between British and US dates) often occur. I would suggest to first format it correctly. One indicator I found from experience is that the dates aren't grouped together when you put a filter and open the filter for the dates.

Comment: I'm not the one importing the data so I don't know how it gets done. I have to work with it like this, not much I can do about it sadly.

Comment: Okay, did you try the filter thing I mentioned earlier? I'm not sure how to ask you so I get the response I'm looking for. Can you identify which dates are badly formatted? I'm suspecting that the 'good dates' are in `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss` format while the bad dates are in `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss`. What happens if you format all of them as `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss`? Do all the dates change, or only the good dates change?

Comment: are all the dates known to be in UK format?

Comment: They are recognized as "general" by Excel. They are originally in dd/mm/yyyy, but some of them are recognized as mm/dd/yyyy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this Custom Format:

```
yyyy/mm/dd h:mm;@
```

To enter it, right click on the cell and Choose Format Cell:

[image: Format Cell]

Then under the `Number` Tab Select `Custom` from the listbox. And enter the provided format in the `Type:` textbox.

[image: Example]

If that doesn't work. Are you *****Absolutely***** Positive that 04/06/2013 09:00:00 IS April 6, 2013 and NOT June 4, 2013??

If this still doesn't work and you have verified that dates are correct.

```
Sub ChangeDateFormat()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim CurrentCell As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim RegEx As Object
Set RegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
RegEx.Global = True

LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Get The Last Row in Column Change A as Needed

For Each CurrentCell In Range("A1:A" & LastRow) ' Loop through all cells. Change Column as needed

    If InStr(CurrentCell.Value, "/") <> 0 Then 'To make sure only convert non converted ones

        RegEx.Pattern = "(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{4}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})" ' Seperate all parts of imported Data into groups
        CurrentCell.Value = RegEx.Replace(CurrentCell.Value, "$3.$2.$1 $4:$5") ' Change order of groups and place into cell.

    End If

Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

*****NOTE: ***** This will only work if **ALL** date values are of `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss` if they are not you will have to add some Error Handling and possibly slightly modify the code as it ***WILL*** cause problems.

This will also work on dates that are inside of other text. If the value of `A1` is

`This is a test 04/06/2013 09:00:00 Lets see what happens`

Then the new value will be

`This is a test 2013.06.04 09:00 Lets see what happens`

Comment: Custom formatting the cells does nothing, I tried them myself too.
I wrote a macro to format the cells, here:  ---
`LastRow = Range("I2").End(xlDown).Row;

    For i = 2 To LastRow;
        If Cells(i, 9).NumberFormat <> "yyyy.mm.dd hh:mm" Then;
            Ttime = Cells(i, 9).Value;
            Cells(i, 9).Value = Format(Ttime, "yyyy.mm.dd hh:mm");
        End If;
    Next`
---  
I can't upload images right now, so here are two contradicting examples:  
Input -> result  |
25/04/2013 10:00:00 -> 2013.04.25 10:00  |
01/04/2013 00:00:00 -> 2013.01.04 00:00

Comment: IF you use `DATEVALUE` on the cell do you get `#VALUE!`?

Comment: Yes, same result with `TIMEVALUE`.

Comment: Then the BEST solution in my eyes, If you can, would be to highlight the Column and do a Text to Columns Using the "Space" as a separator. Then formatting the column as Date then in the drop down selecting `DMY`. This will take care of this issue, but it will also separate the Date and Time into 2 columns not sure if that works for you.  If not I am working on a RegEx Solution to add to my answer. If the Text to Columns does not work please let me know.

Comment: @AttilaBoncok I have Updated my answer. It now includes a Regular Expression that should do what you have asked. Please let me know if it does not meet your needs.

Comment: I went with the RegEx version, works perfectly, thank you :)   Now it's time to learn how RegEx works in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

its simple. . . just follow the steps
select the entire column or even required cells
press right click and select format cell option, a tab window will open
from number tab select date , from locale drop down menu select English (South Africa)
from given options in type select your desired reverse format . . . and you done :)

Comment: Selecting the South African format does nothing to the text.
If then I run my macro, it produces yet again the same results :(

Answer (score 0):

If the month and day are in the wrong place, you can use `"DATE(YEAR(A1),DAY(A1),MONTH(A1))"`, provided it's in date format, and `"DATE(MID(A1,7,4),LEFT(A1,2),MID(A1,4,2))"` if it is in text format